# UICollectionViewCell not filling the entire screen in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

I have a UICollectionView with its cells covering the entire screen. My problem here is that there's a small space on the right that's showing a different cell. I want each cell to cover the full width of the screen.

Here's what I've tried:

1. set min spacing to 0 from Storyboard
2. set each cell to fit the entire view frame

> ```
> private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
>                     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
>                     sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
>     return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
> }
> ```

Is there anything else that I should do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct Swift 3 implementation should be

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

This will make each collection view cell fill up the entire collection view. It should not be private. Now all you need to do is make sure your collection view stretches across the entire view.

Also make sure to extend your ViewController to include UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout for the above method to work and change all section insets to be 0 in Storyboard.

Comment: Also make sure to extend your ViewController to include UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout for the above method to work and change all section insets to be 0 in Storyboard.

>> This was the part that I was missing! Thank you so much!

Comment: saved my day ! Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Adding all 3 delegates are important. Esp. UIDelegateFlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve a little on the top voted answer: you need to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` conformance, though this is not required if you are using `UICollectionViewController` - it already conforms to all the necessary protocols.

Further, a shorter way of implementing the `sizeForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.bounds.size
}
```